# Is this possible in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

What i want is a project with several files in it. Each file has a set of tests. Then I want to be able to run each of those tests.

So right now I have a project but I only have one file: Project.cs. When i run the test through the console/GUI All them tests from Project.cs are run (or a subset if i use the /fixture command).
What I would like (or would like to know if its possible) would be the following.

Have a Project called Tests. In that I have several files FileTests.cs, ControlTests.cs, MiscTests.cs, etc each of these have various tests. Then there is also a Program.cs. I would be able to run the Tests project and choose which of the FileTests, ControlTests, etc I run.

Is that possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [NUnit test categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10).  You can attribute you test with the correct category and then run just tests belonging to that category.  This gives you much more flexibility than having to define them physically as files or assemblies.

Comment: Is this not going to result in just one huge file though?

Comment: @discodowney Before you run the tests, you compile the *.cs files into a single assembly (.dll).  Then the test runner acts upon the assembly.  Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Im using the .exe. Im new to NUnit so im not sure really how it works. But are you saying i can add more .cs files and they can be called using the categories? So theres no need to have a main function (a la C++) where all these tests are added to a test suite?

Comment: @discodowney Typically, you would not have unit tests in the same assembly as production code.  An .exe file is just like a .dll (just one that can be executed).  So the principle is the same.  Many .cs files compile to a single .exe and then you run tests that assembly. So, categories give you a logical grouping of tests to run from the test runner.